# Powershell7 proxy authentication

Tags: powershell, api, proxy, credentials

I'm a PowerShell novice and I inherited some code that's forced me to use Powershell7 over 5.1 on my Windows Server 2012 and now I can't get my credentials to authenticate across the organisation's proxy. I'm thinking there's something in the Powershell7 environment that's not installed/no longer supported/not configured correctly.  The code below works in 5.1 but in 7, I get a message back from our proxy saying it's missing credentials. Can anyone shed light on what to do?

```
#*************************************************************************
# Proxy Credentials 
#*************************************************************************                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                           
[system.net.webrequest]::defaultwebproxy = new-object system.net.webproxy('http://proxy.############')
$username ="###################"
$password ="###################" 
$securePwd = $password| convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds=new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username,$securePwd)
    
$Wcl=New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$Wcl.Proxy.Credentials=$Creds

#*************************************************************************
# Authentication Call   
#*************************************************************************

$uri = 'https://testapi.com/web/authenticate'
$params = '{"userName": "######",
"password": "########"
}' 

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12


$token =Invoke-Webrequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -body $params   -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing |ConvertFrom-Json | Select AuthenticateResult  

write-host $token
#*************************************************************************
```

Comment: PS7 uses environment variables - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1#notes

Answer (score 0):

This was something specific to the service account I was using to log in to the server. Changed the account and it worked on both versions. No idea what the difference was but I got what I needed.